# Error: property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, {} | Observable<any>>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

Why I can't subscribe to the result of concat() operator even when it looks the same as in the documentation and examples at 
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat

I already tried to change to concatMap, or concatAll but I have even more issues, This solution is by far the most elegant one I found.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const trendingRentals = this.rentalService.getRentals().pipe(delay(500));
    const commonRentals = this.rentalService.getCommonRentalsTest().pipe(delay(1000));
    const luxuryRentals = this.rentalService.getLuxuryRentalsTest().pipe(delay(1500));

    const concatenation =  concat( [trendingRentals, commonRentals, luxuryRentals]);
    concatenation.subscribe(
      //Print result
    )
  }

    //All get request are equal but with a different endpoint
    public getCommonRentalsTest(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get('/api/v1/rentals/common');
    }
```

The expedted result is getting all rentals in order then push them to a Results array In the same order.

Comment: `concat` doesn't accepts arrays, you should pass your arguments separately.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ks8chl?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need the ['static' factory function](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat) instead of the [concat operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concat):

```
// Find:
import { concat } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Replace:
import { concat } from 'rxjs';
```

The operator is used with the `pipe` method of another observable. For example:

```
const stream1$: Observable<any> = ...;
const stream2$: Observable<any> = ...;

const concatenated = stream1$.pipe(
    concat(stream2$)
);
```

Comment: You sir are a god :') Thanks you so much!!!! So basically I would have to write something like
const stream1$: Observable<any> = //My http request function
const concatenated = stream1$:pipe( 
     concat(stream2$, stream3$,..., streamX$)
)
Or 
const concatenated = stream1$:pipe( 
     concat(stream2$),
    //.....
    concat(streamX$),
)

Thankyou!!